# Projective image of $G$ equals to $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})$ or $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})$ depending on field extension's parity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $q$ be a power of an odd prime, $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ be the finite field with $q$ elements, and $\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}$ the finite field with $q^{n}$ elements. We have that $n=[\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}:\mathbb{F}_{q}]$.

We define the following group: $$G=\{g\in\text{GL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})|\text{det}(g)\in\mathbb{F}_{q}^{*}\},$$

and we denote by $\overline{G}$ to the image of $G$ in $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})$.

I want to prove that $$\overline{G}=\begin{cases}
\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})\text{ if }n \text{ is odd}\\
\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})\text{ if }n \text{ is even}
\end{cases}.$$

My attempt so far has been as follows:

It is clear that $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})\subseteq \overline{G}$, and since $q$ is odd, we have that $[\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}}):\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})]=2$, so $\overline{G}$ can only be $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})$ or $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})$.

So my idea is now to distinguish the cases by looking at the determinant of the elements of $\text{PGL}(2,\mathbb{F}_{q^{n}})$, but I do not know how to proceed or how to use the fact that the degree of the extension is either odd or even.

If someone could help me, I would appreciate it a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: if $F$ is a field, what are the matrices of $GL_2(F)$ whose image in $PGL_2(F)$ lie in $PSL_2(F)$?

Comment: I know that since the determinant of $PGL_{2}(F)$ is $F^{*}/(F^{*})^{2}$ the matrices or $GL_{2}(F)$ whose imatge lie in $PSL_{2}(F)$ are the ones that have a square as a determinant, but I can not manage to link this with the parity of the field extensions.

Comment: So $\overline{G}=PSL_2(\mathbb{F}_{q^n})$ iff the determinant of every matrix of $G$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, right? Can you go on with this?

Comment: So then if the extension is even the quadratic extension of our base field is Indeed a subextension. Then by the uniqueness of this quadratic extension we can assure that all elements of our base field are squares on it, so they are also squares in the given even extension. Finally, by the previous argument on the determinant we are done. The case with odd extensions follows from the fact that the quadratic extension of our base field can not be a subextension of It. Is this argument right?